# Integral of a log divided by the square root of a polynomial

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I've been trying to evaluate the following integral:

$\int_1^\infty\log(x)\left\{ (1+b)x^3 - x^2 - bx^{5/2}\right\}^{-1/2} \mathrm{d}x$

Without the log, it can be done via two trivial substitutions ($u=\sqrt{x}$ then completing the square), followed by a $sec(t)$ substitution and then finally the Weierstrauss substitution. However, in the presence of the logarithm I always end up with a complicated expression inside the logarithm (starting with a parts integration).

Any hints on how to handle this sort of integral would be greatly appreciated. I should add that Mathematica is unable to do the integral in the presence of the log, but is able in its absence.

Comment: Have you tried applying integral by parts? Take $\log$ to be $u$ and 1/polynomial to be $dv$ for example.

Comment: It looks like after doing the integration by parts the substitution $z=\tan(t/2)$ should be enough to solve the problem.... but I am not quite sure. Oh sorry that's what you are calling the Weiestrauss substitution... I will take a closer look later

Comment: I tried parts first of all, but after solving the polynomial integral I find the integral $v\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}$ to be troublesome.